# Container showing before conditional render value equals true

Tags: reactjs

My `result` variable initially renders as `undefined`

When I use the value `undefined` value to conditionally render a component, the component still shows:

```js
 {result != undefined
          ? result?.map((friend) => (
              <SearchResultsContainer friend={friend.username} />
            ))
          : undefined}
```

Here is my `SearchResultsContainer` component:

```js
 <div className="search__queryWrapper">
        <div className="search__queryWrapperLeft">
          <img src={profile ? profile.imageUrl : undefined} />
          <div className="name__usernameWrapper">
            <h6>{profile ? profile.displayName : undefined}</h6>
            <p>@{friend}</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="search__queryWrapperRight">
          {/* <button onClick={handleAddFriend}>Add</button> */}
        </div>
      </div>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your testing for undefined is always true?

Comment: your question is not clear